# How do I populate two sections in a tableview with two different arrays using swift?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, sections

I have two arrays Data1 and Data2 and I want to populate the data within each of these (they contain strings) into a tableview in two different sections.

The first section should have a heading "Some Data 1" and the second section should be titled "KickAss".

I have both sections populating with data from the first array (but with no headings either).

Here is my code so far:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rowCount = 0
    if section == 0 {
        rowCount = Data1.count
    }
    if section == 1 {
        rowCount = Data2.count
    }
    return rowCount
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let ip = indexPath
    cell.textLabel?.text = Data1[ip.row] as String
    return cell
}
```

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, is it possible for me to identify the section somehow like I did in the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Also, how do I give titles to each section?

Comment: I have been searching for this for a couple hours and this is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**TableView Cells**

You could use a multidimensional array. For example:

```
let data = [["0,0", "0,1", "0,2"], ["1,0", "1,1", "1,2"]]
```

For the number of sections use:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

Then, to specify the number of rows in each section use:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].count
}
```

Finally, you need to setup your cells:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellText = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    //  Now do whatever you were going to do with the title.
}
```

**TableView Headers**

You could again use an array, but with just one dimension this time:

```
let headerTitles = ["Some Data 1", "KickAss"]
```

Now to set the titles for the sections:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section < headerTitles.count {
        return headerTitles[section]
    }

    return nil
}
```

The code above checks to see there's a title for that section and returns it, otherwise `nil` is returned. There won't be a title if the number of titles in `headerTitles` is smaller than the number of arrays in `data`.

**The Result**

[image]

Comment: I try to use this but cannot work, could you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587806/how-to-move-rows-in-uitableview-changing-even-the-section

Answer (score 31):

You could create a `Struct` to hold the data that belongs to a section, as an alternative to my previous answer. For example:

```
struct SectionData {
    let title: String
    let data : [String]

    var numberOfItems: Int {
        return data.count
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        return data[index]
    }
}

extension SectionData {
    //  Putting a new init method here means we can
    //  keep the original, memberwise initaliser.
    init(title: String, data: String...) {
        self.title = title
        self.data  = data
    }
}
```

Now in your view controller you could setup your section data like so:

```
lazy var mySections: [SectionData] = {
    let section1 = SectionData(title: "Some Data 1", data: "0, 1", "0, 2", "0, 3")
    let section2 = SectionData(title: "KickAss", data: "1, 0", "1, 1", "1, 2")

    return [section1, section2]
}()
```

**Section Headers**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return mySections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return mySections[section].title
}
```

Compared to my previous answer, you now don't have to worry about matching the number of `headerTitles` to the number of arrays in `data`.

**TableView Cells**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mySections[section].numberOfItems
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellTitle = mySections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I followed this steps (iOS10, Swift 3) and it works. Quite helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution! Much better to use structs than 2D arrays in this case

Comment: How can apply this solution to the same build up but with dynamic cells? I have 4 different arrays which populate two sections controlled by a segmented control with two segments. The problem I am facing with you solution is that my sections has noch subscript members which is way I cannot fill the cells.

Comment: Great solution, Just a quick note. The `init()` cannot be in an extension. It would give you a `redeclaration` error. Moving the `init()` to the struct body itself solves this issue.

Comment: lazy var mySections: [SectionData] ? declaration? so Need to access in other function

Answer (score 14):

You can determine which section you are in by looking at `indexPath.section`.
To specify the titles, override the function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String!
```

Comment: Thank you all. This was the quick and dirty solution I went with.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 or Swift 5 you can use the code below.

Here a custom header section with filter is shown:

[image]

1. create a project
2. Add table view
3. create UITableView Cell
4. Connect label to uitable view & table with view controller
5. Add bellow code

   ```
   import UIKit

   struct Category {
   let name : String
   var items : [[String:Any]]
   }

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {
     @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   var originalArr = [[String:Any]]();
   var recentArr = [[String:Any]]();
   var searchArrRes = [[String:Any]]()
   var searching:Bool = false

    //
   var sections = [Category]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

   //Assign delegate  don't forget
   txtName.delegate = self
   tableView.delegate = self
   tableView.dataSource = self



   recentArr =   [
       ["name": "Enamul", "number": "+8800000003"],
       ["name": "Enam", "number": "+8800000004"]
   ]

   originalArr = [
       ["name": "abdul", "number": "+8800000001"],
       ["name": "abdin", "number": "+8800000002"],
       ["name": "Enamul", "number": "+8800000003"],
       ["name": "enam", "number": "+8800000004"],
       ["name": "Rafi", "number": "+8800000005"],
       ["name": "Ehaque", "number": "+8800000006"]
      ]

    //my array
     sections = [
         Category(name:"Recent", items:recentArr),
         Category(name:"ALL", items:originalArr)
         ]

         }


      func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
         guard let tableView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }

      tableView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
   //input text
   let searchText  = textField.text! + string

   searchArrRes = self.originalArr.filter({(($0["name"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))})


   if(searchArrRes.count == 0){
       searching = false
   }else{
       searching = true
   }
   self.tableView.reloadData();

   return true
   }


     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   if( searching == true){
       return 1
       }
      return self.sections.count
      }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   if( searching == true){
       return ""
      }
     return self.sections[section].name
     }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if( searching == true){
      return searchArrRes.count
   }else{
       let items = self.sections[section].items
       return items.count
     }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Custom_cell
     //  var dict = itemsA[indexPath.section]

   if( searching == true){
       var dict = searchArrRes[indexPath.row]
       cell.name.text = dict["name"] as? String
       cell.number.text = dict["number"] as? String
    }else{
       let items = self.sections[indexPath.section].items
       let item = items[indexPath.row]
       cell.name.text = item["name"] as? String
       cell.number.text = item["number"] as? String

       }

       return cell
        }


   }
   ```

You can download full source from GitHub.GitHub Like: https://github.com/enamul95/Custom_table_view_section.git

Answer (score 0):

**Can do Sections in Tableview and can change the colours of Header sections**

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tabview: UITableView!

var tablecell = NewTableViewCell()

let data = [["SWIFT", "BALENO", "ALTO", "CIAZ"], ["INNOVA", "GLANZA", "FORTUNER"] , ["BMW X5", "BMW M4", "BMW 7 Series", "BMW X7", "BMW i3"]]

let brand: Array<String> = ["MARUTHI", "TOYOTA", "BMW"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return brand.count
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return data[section].count    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return self.brand[section]

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    // can change the header color of background and title with this code :)

    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellow

    }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell1: NewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! NewTableViewCell

    let text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell1.textLabel!.text = text

    return cell1
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```