# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Array<String>]' with index of type '(section)'. Type' (aka 'section.Type')

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am trying to create a TableView with two headers (Account,Support)
and with text titles in sections.But I am getting errors

I followed answer from this question: [How do I populate two sections in a tableview with two different arrays using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578965/how-do-i-populate-two-sections-in-a-tableview-with-two-different-arrays-using-sw)

Errors:
[image]
and:
[image]

This is my code:

```
 var myTitles = [["Delete current photo","Change profile picture","Change username","Change password"],["Help","Report a problem"]]

let headerTitles = ["Acount", "Support"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myTitles[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3 //This is not complete yet.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section < headerTitles.count {
        return headerTitles[section]
    }

    return nil
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("settingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = myTitles[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, where are you getting the `section` value here:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myTitles[section].count
}
```

Change that to just `return myTitles.count`.